# R: read strings in a data frame and record position of a specific letter

Tags: r, string, parsing

I have a data frame with a column containing strings and their scores. Is there a way to create a new data frame with position of a specific letter in each string and their scores. Here is a sample data frame

```
df<- data.frame( string = do.call(paste0, replicate(10, sample(LETTERS, 5, TRUE), FALSE)),
             start = round(runif(5,100,500),0),
             score = round(runif(5,10,50),1)

head(df)
```

It looks like this:

```
String        start    score
TRIRXBGFPI    219      46.1
QBPWJOTFLQ    430      21.5
PWVEEHKTFW    399      37.2
AWGAFAHGQF    246      16.4
ZDLYRUTZBB    380      32.1
```

Now, I want to be able to read every letter of string and record position of every "B" along with their score. So the expected output will be

```
string         position     start     score
TRIRXBGFPI     6            219       46.1
QBPWJOTFLQ     2            430       21.5
ZDLYRUTZBB     9            380       32.1
ZDLYRUTZBB     10           380       32.1
```

My approach was to use grepl on the string column to filter out the strings without B and then run two for loops to read every letter of every string and record its position. Could someone please suggest a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: remember to set.seed() for reproducibility

Comment: Also column names are not consistent `String` vs. `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another tidyverse option, using `gregexpr`......

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(position = gregexpr("B", String)) %>% 
  unnest(position) %>% 
  filter(position>0)

      String start score position
1 TRIRXBGFPI   219  46.1        6
2 QBPWJOTFLQ   430  21.5        2
3 ZDLYRUTZBB   380  32.1        9
4 ZDLYRUTZBB   380  32.1       10
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `str_locate`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
     mutate(position = str_locate_all(String, "B") %>%
                 map(~ .x[,1])) %>% 
     unnest
#      String start score position
#1 TRIRXBGFPI   219  46.1        6
#2 QBPWJOTFLQ   430  21.5        2
#3 ZDLYRUTZBB   380  32.1        9
#4 ZDLYRUTZBB   380  32.1       10
```

---

Or using `gregexpr` from `base R`

```
lst <- lapply(gregexpr("B", df$String), function(x) as.numeric(x * NA^(x <  0)))
# or use strsplit to split the string and then get the index with which
#lst <- lapply(strsplit(df$String, ""), function(x) {
#       x1 <- which(x == "B")
#       if(length(x1) == 0) NA else x1})
out <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), lengths(lst)),]
out$position <- unlist(lst)
out1 <- out[!is.na(out$position),]
row.names(out1) <- NULL
out1
#      String start score position
#1 TRIRXBGFPI   219  46.1        6
#2 QBPWJOTFLQ   430  21.5        2
#3 ZDLYRUTZBB   380  32.1        9
#4 ZDLYRUTZBB   380  32.1       10
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(String = c("TRIRXBGFPI", "QBPWJOTFLQ", "PWVEEHKTFW", 
"AWGAFAHGQF", "ZDLYRUTZBB"), start = c(219L, 430L, 399L, 246L, 
380L), score = c(46.1, 21.5, 37.2, 16.4, 32.1)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked:) I used the tidyverse solution. Is there a way to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Dear [shashwat-vajpeyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7066479/shashwat-vajpeyi), please accept this answer if you think it's the best solution... Would be useful for later to others.

Comment: @shashwatvajpeyi `str_locate_all(String, regex("B|b") ) `

Comment: @shashwatvajpeyi  Sorry didn't see you edited comment.  You can use `str_locate_all('abBdb', '(?i)B')`

Answer (score 0):

In base `R`:

```
df[["position"]] <- 
   sapply(gregexpr(pattern ='B', df[["String"]]), "[", 1)

subset(df, position > 0)
      String start score position
1 TRIRXBGFPI   219  46.1        6
2 QBPWJOTFLQ   430  21.5        2
5 ZDLYRUTZBB   380  32.1        9
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  String = c("TRIRXBGFPI", "QBPWJOTFLQ", "PWVEEHKTFW", "AWGAFAHGQF", "ZDLYRUTZBB"), 
  start = c(219L, 430L, 399L, 246L, 380L), 
  score = c(46.1, 21.5, 37.2, 16.4, 32.1)
)
```